# Adding a feature to Openlayers Vector source

Tags: openlayers

I want to;

1. get the features from a vector source and
2. for some features, use their coordinates to construct new features, e.g. ol.geom.Circle buffers.

My sample vector source (epsg:3857 projection), with two features (points) that I would like to read their coordinates from:

```
var sampleSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    url: (basePath + '/data/scanner_locations.json'),
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    "EPSG:3857"})).readFeatures(basePath + '/data/scanner_locations.json')
});
```

This layer renders two points on my map.

For 1, to retrieve the source features, if I understand correctly you need to monitor the change event like this:

```
sampleSource.on('change', function(evt){
var source = evt.target;
if (source.getState() === 'ready') {
```

If it is 'ready' you have asynchronously retrieved the source, correct?

Following I try to add something to the source like so:

```
sampleSource.on('change', function(evt){
var source = evt.target;
if (source.getState() === 'ready') {
    var numFeatures = source.getFeatures().length; // if 0, quit ?
    var features = source.getFeatures();
    console.log(features); // gives me the two features
    features.forEach((feature) => {
        if (feature.values_.id === 1){ // if the id property of the feature is 1
            // feature.getGeometry().flatCoordinates should be the center of the circle
            source.addFeature(new ol.Feature({
            // coordinates for the circle center are hardcoded here, radius is 500 meter 
                geometry: new ol.geom.Circle([486524.0550283753, 6801035.6531745335], 500),
                name: 'the buffer'
                // id: 500
            }));
        } // end if
    }) // end forEach
}});
```

This creates a huge stack size, so something is clearly going wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to add features outside of `forEach`. Because features of the source are increasing every loop in your code. Try to code like this:

```
sampleSource.on('change', function(evt){
var source = evt.target;
if (source.getState() === 'ready') {
    var features = source.getFeatures();
    var featuresToAdd = [];
    features.forEach((feature) => {
        if (feature.values_.id === 1){ 
            featuresToAdd.push(new ol.Feature({
                geometry: new ol.geom.Circle([486524.0550283753, 6801035.6531745335], 500),
                name: 'the buffer'
            }));
        } // end if
    }) // end forEach

    source.addFeatures(featuresToAdd);
}});
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!

To make things more complicated, how could I wrap this (getting features and creating buffers from certain geometries) somehow in a function that I can combine with setInterval(createBuffers, 1000*5) for example?
Is there some way of storing the features outside of this event callback? Or what could I do to repeat this process over time?

Comment: May you accept the answer if it solve your problem?

Comment: Accepted the answer. However, would be very grateful if you could comment on my last comment. I.e. how can I get these features on a timed interval?

Comment: `setInterval(createBuffers, 1000 * 5);
function createBuffers() {
    var features = vectorLayer.getSource().getFeatures();
    features.forEach((feature) => {
        if (feature.values_.id === 1) {
            featuresToAdd.push(new ol.Feature({
                geometry: new ol.geom.Circle([486524.0550283753, 6801035.6531745335], 500),
                name: 'the buffer'
            }));
        }
    });
}`

Comment: If the interval is really short and the source has not yet been (fully) loaded getFeatures() does not return all features. Perhaps I should monitor the load process and then fire off my interval'd functions?